# flask not redirecting to new page after redirect(url_for())

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I have a simple app that needs to run a subprocess.call in celery and simply return some text to the screen as it's been successfully submitted.

Try as I might, I have been unable to make the redirect(url_for()) do anything.  I see in the log that I get a 302 and a 200 but no new page in the browser window.

Here is my the pertinent part of my server.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from flask import Flask, url_for, jsonify, request, make_response, render_template, json, flash, Markup, redirect
from celery import Celery, states
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import pandas as pd
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.secret_key = 'random string'
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'amqp://cluster:cluster@localhost/myvhost'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'amqp://cluster:cluster@localhost/myvhost'
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/showPrevNext')
def showPrevNext():
    return render_template('prevnext.html')

@app.route('/PrevNext',methods=['GET','POST'])
def prevNext():
    _uid      = request.form['inputUid']
    _db   = request.form['inputName']
    _TableName = request.form['inputTableName']
    if  _id:
        uid = _uid
        if _db:
            db = _db
            if _TableName:
                TableName = _TableName
                flash("Running  images!")
                return redirect(url_for('main'))
                create_some_stuff.delay(uid,db,TableName)
```

create_some_stuff is a celery task that runs fine but I am having trouble making the redirect work.  After many hours of toying, I hope one of you can help please?

output from the console is:

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 270-380-963
192.168.200.238 - - [15/Feb/2018 16:55:07] "POST /PrevNext HTTP/1.1" 302 -
192.168.200.238 - - [15/Feb/2018 16:55:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Am I missing something simple?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am having trouble making the redirect work.

Maybe conditional expressions in *prevNext* doesn't lead to functions return. Try to move *return* to the first level and see what will happen. Like so:

```
@app.route('/PrevNext',methods=['GET','POST'])
def prevNext():
    _uid      = request.form['inputUid']
    _db   = request.form['inputName']
    _TableName = request.form['inputTableName']
    if  _id:
        uid = _uid
        if _db:
            db = _db
            if _TableName:
                TableName = _TableName
                flash("Running  images!")
                create_some_stuff.delay(uid,db,TableName)
    return redirect(url_for('main')) #moved
```